# Oracle query to fetch the data from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query to fetch the avg count per person.

```
SELECT
    Y.name, 
    ROUND(SUM(Y.final_count) / (31)) AVG_COUNT 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         day, name, final_count,
         NVL(last_value(decode(final_count, 0, CAST(null AS number), final_count)) ignore nulls over (order by day, final_count desc), 0) final_count
    FROM
        (WITH days (day) AS
         (
             SELECT date '2020-05-01' FROM dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT day + 1 FROM days WHERE day < last_day(day)
         ),
         names (name) AS
         (
             SELECT DISTINCT name FROM person
         )
         SELECT
             d.day, n.name, COUNT(p.name) AS final_count
         FROM 
             days d
         CROSS JOIN
             names n
         LEFT JOIN
             person p ON p.name = n.name
                      AND p.date_created >= d.day
                      AND p.date_created < d.day + 1
         GROUP BY
             d.day, n.name
         ORDER BY
             d.day, n.name) x
     WHERE
         x.name = ( 'Person_1')) Y   
GROUP BY 
    Y.name;
```

In the above query I have to put the name of the person manually, Is there any way I can get the name from the person table and feed the above as a subquery?

In the person table, I have more than one person. My final output should look like this. It works with the cursor but I don't want to write a cursor because of requirements.

```
Person        Avg_Count
Person1       10
Person2       11
Person3       3
Person4       22
```

Example is here:
[enter link description here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa912e964b26a8877be9652f06ee6576)

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example] (yes, minimizing the problem would also help tremendously...), i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the line:

```
where x.name= ( 'Person_1')
```

The inner CTE is already getting all the names.

I don't think the calculation is doing what you want, and you've made it rather complicated. Your previous question seems to have been an X/Y problem...

I think you can just do:

```
select p.name,
  round(count(*) / extract(day from last_day(date '2020-05-01'))) as avg_count
from person p
where p.date_created >= date '2020-05-01'
and p.date_created < date '2020-05-01' + interval '1' month
group by p.name
order by p.name;
```

which will give all the people with any rows and their average for that month.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f71cac8b53008282f5834eea1b45f20a)

Or if the inner part from your previous question is correct, then just get the average from that as an inline view or another CTE:

```
with days (day) as (
  select date '2020-05-01' from dual
  union all
  select day + 1 from days where day < last_day(day)
),
names (name) as (
  select distinct name from person
  -- possibly only within the target month?
),
counts (day, name, count_person) as (
  select d.day, n.name,
    coalesce(
      last_value(nullif(count(p.name),0) ignore nulls)
        over (partition by n.name order by d.day), 0) as count_person
  from days d
  cross join names n
  left join person p on p.name = n.name
  and p.date_created >= d.day
  and p.date_created < d.day + 1
  group by d.day, n.name
)
select name, round(avg(count_person))
from counts
group by name
order by name
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ce48efad49c7c81c06d31e4a065571d)

Comment: Inner CTE is getting the names but final count is messed up so i have to put the individual name. I dont want to remove the line for where filter

Comment: But including all the names in the where clause via a subquery will be the same as not having that clause at all? The final count being wrong doesn't seem to be anything to do with which names are included; your calculation is just wrong, even for a single name. If that simple query doesn't give you the answer you want then, as StickyBit said, edit the question to give sample data and the result that acmtually matches that data, as well as explaining the logic.

Comment: @shanky - if you want the average of the values from the previous question then you don't want to move the `last_value` part to a higher level; that means you'll get the same answer whichever single person you filter on, I believe; and the same value for all names with no filter. Anyway, I've added how to just average the values from the previous question.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your answer. Your answer works perfectly!